# Andengine livewall paper : Do a texture atlas with size 1280*800 support in all devices?

Tags: andengine, textures

I am developing a live wallpaper using Andengine , I know that in some devices the maximum size allowed  for texture atlas is 1024*1024.I  and I like to create a background image of size 1280 *800.
Want to know do this will support in all devices?

advance thanks for all suggestions and Ideas

Comment: you kind of answered your own question there - maybe I'm misunderstanding though

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you for respoonse,My doubt is this device support 1024*1024, But in my case I am sing 800 for height do this will give me chance to 1280 in width, I know a blunder question,but I dont know the details behind the texture alts size support :(.... Sir, It will be very helpfull if you can give me some instructions on  the best way to setting BG in live wallpaper. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't do that.

Also, you shouldn't. A huge live wallpaper will make a device run slowly if it eats upp all of its memory. You should choose a background image size that is appropriate to the device.

Take a look at how android handles the selection of images from the /resources folders. It uses different sized images for different displays:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

This is a sensible best practice that you should follow in all of your mobile development: use the least memory you can. Tailor your content to the device capabilities as much as is reasonably possible.

One-size-fits-all is really one-size-fits-none in mobile development.

Here is one strategy that might work for you
Get the display width and height when creating your engine, then choose the appropriate sized background based on that result.

```
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int cameraWidth = display.getWidth();
    int cameraHeight = display.getHeight();

    String deb = String.format("Screen: %d / %d",cameraWidth,cameraHeight);
    Log.d("Debug:", deb);

    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, cameraWidth,cameraHeight);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, 
        new RatioResolutionPolicy(cameraWidth, cameraHeight), this.mCamera));
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for valuable answer, Sir Can you help me by suggesting any article or any post on any where on setting bg for andengine live livewallpaper that cares for different device display ratio ..

Comment: Added more info above. You should be able to google detecting display size on your own and figure out a solution from there.